# OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier - google maps - get a special icon for spiderable markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I try to implement [OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier](https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier) to view the user multiple markers, when they are on the exact same location. With the following code, everything works fine:

```
function initMap() {

var osterreich = {lat: 47.7059673, lng: 13.2364467};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('countrymap'), {
    zoom: 7,
    center: osterreich,
    streetViewControl: false,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    scaleControl: false,
    fullscreenControl: false,   
    draggableCursor: 'pointer',
    gestureHandling: 'greedy'
});

var oms = new OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier(map, {
    markersWontMove: true,
    markersWontHide: true,
    basicFormatEvents: true,
    keepSpiderfied: true,
    legWeight: 0,
    nearbyDistance: 0.001
}); 


if(markerpositions !== null){   

for(var i=0;i<markerpositions.length;i++){

    var position = markerpositions[i];
    var positiondata = position.split(","); 
    var lat = parseFloat(positiondata[0]);
    var lng = parseFloat(positiondata[1]);
    var markerposition = {lat: lat, lng: lng};

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({

        position: markerposition,
        map: map,
        icon: jobpinlink[i],
        draggable: false 
    }); 

    oms.addMarker(marker);

    }
}
```

Now, I want a different icon for the markers which are "spiderable". So the user can visually recognize, that there is more than one marker. I tried to realize this with many variations of the code from the documentation.

My problem is, that the google-maps "build-up" from the [documentation](https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier/blob/gh-pages/demo-2.html) is different from mine and my javascript skills are to weak to see thru. I don´t know what to adapt.

```
oms.addListener('format', function(marker, status) {
    var iconURL = status == OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier.markerStatus.SPIDERFIED ? 'pin_spiderable.png' :
      status == OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier.markerStatus.SPIDERFIABLE ? 'pin_spiderable.png' :
      status == OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier.markerStatus.UNSPIDERFIABLE ? 'pin_spiderable.png' : 
      null;
    var iconSize = new google.maps.Size(23, 32);
    marker.setIcon({
      url: iconURL,
      size: iconSize,
      scaledSize: iconSize  // makes SVG icons work in IE
    });
  });
```

When I copy the Code from above after `var oms`, it does weird things :). The icons get loaded, but only after one click on the marker, not on the first visit although the `marker.setIcon` throws an `Uncaught InvalidValueError: setIcon: not a string; and no url property; and no path property`-error.

And I only want to change the *spiderable-marker* icon. When I only leave `status == OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier.markerStatus.SPIDERFIABLE ? 'pin_spiderable.png' : null;` in the *var iconURL*, no icon-change happens, even on the second click.

Regards Stefan

Answer (score 0):

I am using following code and it works for me.

```
let oms = new OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier(map, {markersWontMove: true, markersWontHide: true});

oms.addListener('format', function (marker, status) {
    let iconURL = (status === OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier.markerStatus.SPIDERFIED) ? 'pin_spiderable.png' :
        (status === OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier.markerStatus.SPIDERFIABLE) ? 'pin_spiderable.png' :
        (status === OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier.markerStatus.UNSPIDERFIABLE) ? 'pin_spiderable.png' :
                null;
    marker.setIcon({
        url: iconURL,
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(32, 32)  // makes SVG icons work in IE
    });
});
oms.addMarker(marker);
```

Comment: Well, i tried your script, but the icons only change after the first click on a spiderfyable Icon and I still get the InvalidValueError. Do you have any Idea why?

Comment: When defining your markers, you only need the position as the icon will be used through overlappingMarkerSpiderfier. So change your code from below to further below.
```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({

        position: markerposition,
        map: map,
        icon: jobpinlink[i],
        draggable: false 
    }); 
```
Change to
```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({

        position: markerposition,
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this is to change basicFormatEvents:true to basicFormatEvents:false or completely remove it by default it is false.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Help us understand better: why does changing `basicFormatEvents` fix this problem?